# System of equations. Solve for y or x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{ (x - 1) }{3} + \frac{ (y + 2) }{2} = 3$$
$$\frac{ (1 - x) }{6} - \frac{ (y - 4) }{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

I've tried

$$\frac{ ( x - 1 ) ( 1 - x ) }{3} + \frac{ ( y + 2 ) }{2} = 3$$
$$\frac{ ( 1 - x ) ( x - 1 ) }{6} - \frac{ ( y - 4 ) }{2} = \frac{ 1 }{2}$$

$$\frac{ ( -x^2 + 2x - 1 ) }{3} + \frac{ ( y + 2 ) }{2} = 3$$
$$\frac{ ( -x^2 + 2x - 1) }{6} - \frac{ ( y - 4 ) }{2} = \frac{ 1 }{2}$$

$$\frac{ -1}{2} x \frac{ ( -x^2 + 2x - 1 ) }{3} + \frac{ ( y + 2 ) }{2} = 3 = \frac{ ( x^2 - 2x + 1 ) }{6} - \frac{ ( y - 2 ) }{4} = -1.5$$
$$\frac{ ( -x^2 + 2x - 1 )}{6} - \frac{ ( y - 4 ) }{2} = \frac{ 1 }{2}$$

$$\frac{ -( y - 2 ) }{4} = -1.5$$
$$\frac{ -( y - 4 ) }{2} = .5$$

$$\frac{ -( y - 2 ) }{4} \frac{ 1 }{2} x \frac{ -( y - 4 ) }{2} = \frac{ -( y - 4 ) }{4} = -1$$

$$\frac{ ( -2y - 6 ) }{4} = -1$$

$$-2y - 6 = -4 = -2y = 2 = y = 1$$

The answer is x = 4 and y = 2

If I factor $$-2y - 6$$ into $2(1 + 3)$!YOU DID FACT

Comment: Hint: Take your first equation, clear the fractions, and solve for $y$.  Then substitute for $y$ into the second equation and solve for $x$.  Then, substitute your answer for $x$ into the expression for $y$ to find $y$.

Comment: Have no clue, how to do that.

Comment: Multiply by the first equation by a number that has both $3$ and $2$ as a factor and then perform some simplifying algebra...

Comment: X = 4, y = 2. So, I don't get that answer 14 - 2x over 3

Comment: You now substitute that $y$ into the second equation and solve for $x$!

Comment: May someone solve $y$, in a new way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the two equations,
$$\frac{(x-1)}{3}+\frac{(y+2)}{2}=3$$
$$\frac{(1-x)}{6}-\frac{(y-4)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Before doing anything get rid of the fractions. In the first equation if we multiply both the left hand side and the right hand side by $6$, we get
$$6\cdot \left[\frac{(x-1)}{3}+\frac{(y+2)}{2}\right]=6\cdot3$$
$$\implies 6\cdot \frac{(x-1)}{3}+6\cdot \frac{(y+2)}{2}=6\cdot3$$
$$\implies 2(x-1)+3(y+2)=18$$
since $\frac{6}{3}=2$ and $\frac{6}{2}=3$ and $6\cdot 3=18$. Now simplify,
$$2(x-1)+3(y+2)=18$$
by first distributing $2$ across the first term and $3$ across the second term, getting
$$2x-2+3y+6=18$$
now isolate the variables,
$$2x+3y=18-6+2=14$$
Solve for $y$, by subtracting $2x$ and dividing by $3$, to get
$$y=\frac{14-2x}{3}.$$ 
Now take the second equation and first get rid of the fractions again by multiplying by $6$ in this case, so that
$$\frac{(1-x)}{6}-\frac{(y-4)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ 
becomes
$$(1-x)-3(y-4)=3.$$
Now plug in the expression for $y$ we just obtained, i.e. $y=\frac{14-2x}{3}$, and the substitution yields,
$$(1-x)-3(y-4)=3$$
$$\implies (1-x)-3\left[\frac{(14-2x)}{3}-4\right]=3$$
$$\implies (1-x)-14+2x+12=3$$
$$\implies x=4.$$
Now solve for $y$, by plugging in $x=4$ into $y=\frac{14-2x}{3}$.

Comment: How did you get 18? Plus, can I factor $$\frac{ ( -2y - 6 ) }{4} = -1$$ into $$\frac{ 2(-y - 3 ) }{2} = -2$$ ??? With the 2 being cancelled out on the second, because I multiplied it by -1

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation by $6$. You agree, $6\cdot 3=18$, no?

Comment: No. $\frac{2(-y-6)}{2}=(-y-6)$, don't you see the $2$'s cancel each other out? In general $\frac{ab}{a}=b$.

Comment: Oh, I just didn't know you take the 6 and factor it to 3 and 2. I thought you were cross multiplying, because that's the way it looked, and the 6 was absent. Plus, you ommited a number from the second equation.

Comment: My head is messed up right now. I have been working on this problem since last night.

Comment: Let me just write it in detail...one second.

Comment: Ok... Ty so much. I really need to get a tutor.

Comment: Ok I understand now Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Your first and second equations are obviously equivalent to
$$2x+3y=14\\x+3y=-10$$
respectively